Systemd service to start only after CIFS mount
I have a little home server (an old PC really) running a few services
under Proxmox hypervisor, one of which is the qBittorrent server. 
It is installed in a separate LXC container, on an Ubuntu 24.04 base system. 
All downloads are saved on a separate local home-made PI-based NAS share that is mounted inside the qBittorrent container using CIFS in fstab, on /mnt/Vault.
My problem is, every time I need to restart the qBT container, the torrents will throw a "missing files" error, as, I think, the "qBittorrent-nox" service starts quicker than the NAS share gets mounted inside the container. 
It seems simply a matter of the qBT service being faster than the mount –
and so it didn't find the necessary files in time. 
Afterwards, when I check the mount, it is there,
so I can eliminate any mounting issues, other than not being fast enough.
So, is it possible to somehow define a condition in the qBT service file
to wait and start only after the mount is present?
Here is the service file:
[Unit]
Description=qBittorrent Command Line Client
After=network.target
 
[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=qbittorrent-nox
UMask=007 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox -d --webui-port=8080
Restart=on-failure
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I'm thinking the After directive under the Unit section,
but I'm not sure. 
Somehow, I should maybe incorporate a response from fstab in there,
to confirm that all mounts were successful?
Any ideas how to put this in practice? 
My Linux skills are limited, so I'll do my best to follow any proposals.

After= is correct – you should add an After= for the .mount unit that represents your filesystem, e.g. After=mnt-data.mount.
Although in general you should pair it with either Requires= (in your case) or Wants= for correctness reasons, i.e. because After= in itself doesn't cause the mount to be started; it relies on the boot process already starting it. So if you manually systemctl start the service, but the SMB1 filesystem isn't mounted yet, then After= would just do nothing.
[Unit]
After=mnt-Vault.mount
Requires=mnt-Vault.mount

This can often be simplified using RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/Vault which automatically expands to Requires and After for all .mount units (known to systemd) along the specified path.

Somehow, I should maybe incorporate a response from fstab in there, to confirm that all mounts were successful?

Pretend that there's no such thing. The fstab isn't handled as a single unit but converted to multiple independent .mount units.
The conversion does group then into local-fs.target and remote-fs.target for ordering After them, and I suppose you could Require them as well. But still, pretend that "there's no such thing" when it comes to checking the success of the entire fstab.
(Nor is it usually necessary; if your service relies on mount A, then it should only care about success of mount A – not about entirely unrelated mounts X and Y.)

1 I will insist on calling it SMB, because the name "CIFS" only applied to a specific variant of SMBv1, and if your share is hosted by an up-to-date Samba, then you aren't using SMBv1; you're using SMBv3 which is an entirely different protocol.

If you would mount /mnt/Vault with a mount-unit instead of fstab, you could add After= and Wants= the to [Unit]-section of the qbt-service, Like this:
[Unit] 
Description=qBittorrent Command Line Client 
After=mnt-Value.mount
# Service fails, if mount fails
Requires=mnt-Value.mount

[Service] 
Type=forking 
User=root 
Group=qbittorrent-nox 
UMask=007 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox -d --webui-port=8080 
Restart=on-failure

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The mount-unit would need the path name (e.g. mnt-Vault.mount) and would look like this:
[Unit]
Description=my network share
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=//<ip-adress>
Where=/mnt/Vault
Type=cifs
# With the options you need to tinker around, what works for you
Options=credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=2.1,noserverino

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

To automatically mount the mount-unit, you also need a automount-unit, which got the same name as the mount-unit (e.g. mount-Vault.automount) and looks like this:
[Unit]
Description=Automount networkshare

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/Vault

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

You could save the mount-units under /etc/systemd/system.
After adding the units you need to reload with systemctl daemon-reload. You can see if it worked, by listing the mount-units with systemctl list-units --type=mounts.
For further information, you can read more over here:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.mount.html

"To automatically mount the mount-unit, you also need a automount-unit" is not really correct. Automount units specifically handle automatic mounting on access, which is redundant here because your example already has WantedBy=multi-user.target which provides automatic mounting on boot (although should really be WantedBy=local-fs.target).
